# How to wait for a response before continuing in the program? (Nodejs with Elasticsearch)

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, promise, response

I have this method called getFormattedURI(uri) which takes in a URI and parses it for contents like name of website and queries. This method sends a request to the URI and does things with the response. However, I want all the code after getFormattedURI(uri) to wait until that method is completed because I use the return values from that method in the following code. It is something like this:

```
function getFormattedURI(uri) {
    request.get(uri).end((err, res) => {
        //(using superagent request) do stuff with res and return parsed uri
    });
}

...
let x = getFormattedURI('www.google.com');
//do stuff with x like index it into Elasticsearch
```

I want my code to wait until I get a response from the request, and not go past the function call immediately. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Node.js doesn't expose any synchronous methods for this. Not that it's really necessary. Why don't you just put the code in the callback?

Comment: just like 4castle suggested you can put stuff in callback, or if you absolutely must you can use .ajax with async : false option  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Its considered very bad practice to block(sync) the JS thread, and your case is very easy and straight forward to do using callbacks.

and if you want to get fancy, you can use promise(provided the JS engine support promise, or you should use third party library)

Sample using promise :

```
function getFormattedURI() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request.get(uri).end((err, res) => {
            //(using superagent request) do stuff with res and return parsed uri
            resolve(res);
        });
    });
}


getFormattedURI('www.google.com').then(function(res) {

})
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking of as soon as I saw the question!